# Custom form component, ControllValueAccessor and errors Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm using form validators with angular reactive form but I'm stuck with a custom form component.

I developed a generic form component : a datetime-picker. This custom input is injected in my form campaign (add a campaign with a name, and two dates : begin and end) but I would like to control it with a custom form validator (check if the date and time are in the good format). I read severals tutorials on ControlValueAccessor/Custom Form validators but this is the first time I'm using it with custom form component.

**campaign.component.ts**

```html
import {FormComponent} from '../../coreModule/forms/formComponent';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class CampaignFormComponent extends FormComponent implements OnInit {

    currentCampaign: Campaign = new Campaign();
    campaignForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder

    ) {
        super();

        this.campaignForm = fb.group({
            'name': fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
            'date_begin': fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
            'date_end': fb.control('', [Validators.required])
        });

        this.initFormValues();
    }

       initFormValues() {
        this.campaignForm.patchValue(this.currentCampaign);
    }

    formValidate() {
       // form validation
       console.log(this.campaignForm.value);
    }
}
```

**campaign.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="campaignForm" (ngSubmit)="formValidate()" >
            <mat-card-content class="mat-card-content">
                <div fxLayout="row">
                    <div fxLayout="column" fxflex="100%">

                        <mat-form-field class="form-input">
                            <input matInput formControlName="name" maxlength="255"
                            placeholder="Name" > 
                            <mat-error *ngIf="!campaignForm.controls['name'].valid && campaignForm.controls['name'].touched">
                                {{'general.form.error.required' | translate }}
                            </mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <datetime-picker formControlName="date_begin" [label]="labelDateBegin" [defaultValue]="currentCampaign.date_begin"></datetime-picker>
                        <datetime-picker formControlName="date_end" [label]="labelDateEnd" [defaultValue]="currentCampaign.date_end"></datetime-picker>
                    </div>
                </div>        
            </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-footer style="margin:0 auto;">
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center">
                    <button mat-button type="button" [routerLink]="['/campaigns']" mat-raised-button color="warn">Cancel</button>

                    <button type="submit" color="primary" mat-raised-button style="margin-left: 8px;" [disabled]="campaignForm.invalid">Submit</button>

                </div>
            </mat-card-footer>
        </form>
```

**datetimepicker.component.ts**

```
export const DATEPICKER_VALUE_ACCESSOR : any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatePickerComponent),
    multi: true,
  };

@Component( {
    selector: 'datetime-picker',
    templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html',
    providers: [DATEPICKER_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
    styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.scss']
} )

export class DatePickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer2
    ) {

    }


    ngOnInit() {     
    }

    /**
     *  ControlValueAccessor functions **
     **/

    // the method set in registerOnChange, it is just 
    // a placeholder for a method that takes one parameter, 
    // we use it to emit changes back to the form
    private propagateChange = (_: any) => { };


    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value) {
            this.currentDate = value;
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched() {}

    /**
     * Close the compon"ent when click outside this.
     * @param $event
     */
    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) clickedOutside($event){
        this.transformDate();
     }

    @Input()
    set defaultValue(value){
        if(value!=null){
            this.currentDate = value;
            if(this.typePicker=='timer'){
                this.currentDateTranformed = this.datePipeFr.transform(this.currentDate, 'HH:mm');   
            } else {
                this.currentDateTranformed = this.datePipeFr.transform(this.currentDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
            }
        }
    }


clickDatepicker(){
  // some code here
}

    /**
     * function when click in component
     * @param event
     */
    onConfirm(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if(event.toElement.className=="owl-dateTime-btn owl-corner-bottomLeft owl-dateTime-btnConfirm") {
            this.transformDate();
        } else if(event.toElement.className=="owl-dateTime-btn owl-corner-bottomRight owl-dateTime-btnClose") {
            this.currentDate = "";
            this.transformDate();
        }
        this.propagateChange(this.currentDate);
    }
    // for view
    transformDate(){
        this.overlay = "datetimepicker-overlay-off";
        if(this.typePicker=='timer'){
            this.currentDateTranformed = this.datePipe.transform(this.currentDate, 'HH:mm');   
        } else {
            this.currentDateTranformed = this.datePipe.transform(this.currentDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
        }
        this.valueSelected.emit(this.currentDate);
    }

}
```

**datetimepicker.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field class="form-input">
    <input matInput name="datePickerInput" maxlength="255" placeholder="{{label}}" (click)="clickDatepicker();"
     [(ngModel)]="currentDateTranformed" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</mat-form-field>

<owl-date-time [inline]="true" [(ngModel)]="currentDate" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" #datePicker [class]="overlay" 
showButtons="true" (click)="onConfirm($event)" [locale]="lang" [type]="typePicker"></owl-date-time>
```

Thank you !

Comment: what is your question ? :)

Comment: How to return and show the error from my form component to my custom form component ?